# Xceed WPF DataGrid - Master/Detail : Change background color of cell in detail section based on data

Tags: wpf, xaml, master-detail, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I'm new to WPF which might explain the difficulty I'm having doing this.  As an example of what I want to do, I'm using a simplified version of Xceed's MasterDetial sample app which has Employees as a Master and the Orders associated with each employee as Details.  The DetailConfigurations are working.  I'm using this example because I need to get the same functionality working in a much larger and more complicated application.

Where I'm running into trouble is trying to change the background color of a single DataCell in the detail section.  By way of example, say I've expanded the first master (employee) row and get back a list of orders.  Each order has a ShipCountry field.  If the value of ShipCountry is "Poland", I want to change the background of the ShipCountry cell (and ONLY that cell) to Red.

The below does it for the entire row, despite there being a target type of DataCell.  I can't figure out why this would be the case.  I've tried any number of different approaches based on things I've found in searching for this problem but none have worked.  I figure I'm missing something obvious and it's a simple binding issue but that's where being a newbie to WPF (and to the Xceed grid) is hindering me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```xml
<xcdg:DataGridControl
     x:Name="grid"
     AllowDetailToggle="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainPageParams.Singleton},Path=AllowDetailToggle}"
     AutoCreateDetailConfigurations="False"
     CellEditorDisplayConditions="None"
     EditTriggers="BeginEditCommand,ActivationGesture,ClickOnCurrentCell"
     ItemScrollingBehavior="Immediate"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsEmployees}}">
        <xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>

                    <!-- Fieldname not a valid property...
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=ShipCountry}" Value="Poland"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Self, Path=FieldName}" Value="ShipCountry"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    -->

                    <!-- This changes the entire row to Red, not just the ShipCountry field-->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShipCountry}" Value="Poland">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
        <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue with your first example is:

```
Binding="{Binding Self, Path=FieldName}"
```

This is what I do on mine.  I just swapped to using your parameters.

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=FieldName}" Value="ShipCountry" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ShipCountry}" Value="Poland" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Or another way I do it is in the column's datatemplate:

**Column Declaration:**

```
<xcdg:Column Title="Ship Country"
    CellContentTemplate="{StaticResource ShipCountryDataTemplate}"
    FieldName="ShipCountry" />
```

**DataTemplate**

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ShipCountryDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type dat:Order}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt" 
            Text="{Binding}" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=xcdg:DataRow, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.EmployeeChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is working for me, at least in this specific scenario.  The real implementation is more complicated and requires a converter to look-up the data elsewhere so I'll build off this and hope it all still works in the end!